# How can I install GreenAsia Inc. 2.4G RX driver on manjaro manually?

Tags: keyboard, linux-device-driver, manjaro

I have manjaro as my operating system and my wireless keyboard is not working with usb or bluetooth. the bluetooth way, it types after seconds i pressed any button.
I found this page https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0e8f-00a7 but I dont know how to download or anything.

Comment: This question might be better suited for Manjaro support forums (https://manjaro.org/support/). Stackoverflow is primarily for software-development related questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out later in life that the keyboard I used was not a legitimate hardware designed from the company (other Bluetooth devices work perfectly), and the USB dongle was exchanged with another hardware.